# Can't watch error logs in onePlus3 OxygenOs 3.2.8

Tags: android, android-studio, oneplusthree

I am an Android application developer. Whenever any of my application crashes I can't see the error log as the app get restarted clearing all the previous logs. How can I disable this behaviour or any other way through which I can see my error logs.

Basically to my understanding the app crash dialog is never coming and as the app is restarted all the previous logs are being flushed from android studio logcat.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below instructions -

1. Go to Run Menu in Toolbar.
2. Select Edit Configurations...
3. Select Android App -> app on left panel.
4. Now on right panel select Miscellaneous Tab.
5. Now uncheck - Clear log before launch.

Your work is done.